# Maximum of a part of a signal

Tags: matlab, max, signal-processing

In a `signal` created like so:

```
Tinitial =0; 
Tfinal = 1;
NbEch = 300;
Tech = (Tfinal - Tinitial)/(NbEch-1); 
t = Tinitial : Tech: Tfinal; % time vector
signal = sin(2*pi*t*3) + 0.25*sin(2*pi*t*50) + randn(size(t))/10;

figure
plot(t,signal)
```

I want to calculate the signal maximum between 0% and 10% of the time and between 50% and 60% of the time. I've tried using `ginput` on the figure, but want this to be done automatically because I have several curves of the same type in a loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calculate the time percentages

```
tpct = (t-Tinitial)/(Tfinal - Tinitial);
```

Calculate maximums using logical indexing and the percentage vector we just made.

```
sigMax0_to_10  = max( signal(tpct >= 0.0 & tpct <= 0.1) ); % max between 0% - 10% time
sigMax50_to_60 = max( signal(tpct >= 0.5 & tpct <= 0.6) ); % max between 50% - 60% time
```

You could easily adapt this to have your upper and lower thresholds in an array and loop over them.

Comment: for the calculation of tpct if: `t = t(4.8 : 5.6)`, `Tinitial = 4.8` and `Tfinal = 5.6` and the difference `CT = 0.8`, is the same reasoning?

Comment: @Mac If you want to relate the percentage directly to `t`, irrespective of how `t` is calculated, then just use `max(t)` and `min(t)` instead of `Tfinal` and `Tinitial` respectively in that equation.